# Conectar MySQL Workbench con una instancia de mysql en Google Compute Engine

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-platform

Tengo una instancia de Google compute Engine en la cual cree una instancia de mysql. ¿Quisiera saber como me puedo conectar a esta instancia desde MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Pues solo necesitas el nombre del servidor y el nombre de la instancia para poder conectarte, claro debes de configurar en tu instancia algun usuario y contraseña para acceder y los permisos y privilegios que deseas que tenga, ademas debes de configurar que acepte conexiones remotas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud cuenta con reglas de conexión bastante estrictas.

para desarrollo local recomiendan el uso de proxy mediante [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)

basicamente es un proxy que permite conectar tu maquina al servidor SQL.

otro caso es la maquina que va a usar recurrentemente el servidor SQL, debe ser agregado a las ip validas del cortafuegos ([Red VPC)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/firewalls)

**Los pasos son:**

1. ir a la consola de Google Cloud
2. Red VPC
3. reglas de cortafuegos
4. agregar la ip que podra acceder al servidor sql

lamentablemente toda la [documentacion](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/firewalls) esta en ingles